# How to add name to firebase password login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase `authentication` with a provider (facebook, google) I can query the user's `name`.
I want to enable password authentication as well.
The SDK offers only `email` and `password` parameters.

Can I attach the name of the user to the generated token along or I have to keep its name in my `db`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the user's display name by doing a profile update. I'm not sure what platform you're using, but here are the guides for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile), and [web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try it. I'm using `verifyIdToken` at my backend to verify the user and retrieve the `email` and `name`. If I set the `displayName` field in the token, does the admin sdk retrieve it as `name`? It works like this with the provider API

Comment: After updating the user profile data, you can call `user.getIdToken(true)` to force refresh the ID token to ensure it has the updated profile information. This will be reflected with you call `verifyIdToken`.